# TFS branch- marked as read only when mapped locally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I had branched out from our QA branch on TFS, mapped it locally and tried making changes to the code locally. When trying to save my code changes, it gives me a warning saying that " the file is write-protected(read only). This has never happened before to me. We tried doing the same thing on my teammates workstation and it works fine for him.
Is it a permissions issue....am I doing something wrong while branching out? I am connected to the right tfs server. I'm not sure what might be causing the files in the branch to be read only.

I'd highly appreciate your help on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys...I'm going to have to answer my own question. 
It was the connection to our main tfs server. I connected to the backup tfs server and it works just fine. However, what is baffling is that my teammates can work with the main tfs server just fine.Only I can't.Still puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be that your solution went offline.
What you can try is connect to your main TFS server, Load the solution then just goto File->SourceControl->go online.
Hope this will solve your problem as it solved mine.. :-)